# Simple Form & Time Zone - time zone not displaying in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use simple form in my rails 4 app.

I have a form field for choosing a time zone, as follows:

```
<%= f.input :time_zone, priority: /Australia/, label: 'Your time zone', :label_html => { :class => 'question-project' }, placeholder: 'Select', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 650px', class: 'response-project'} %>
```

The form inputs work properly.

In my view I then have:

```
    <div class="bobp"> <%= @profile.time_zone %> </div>
```

When I test that - nothing appears in the field. When I inspect element in google chrome nothing appears in the field.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Did you check the database?Is it getting saved?

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your input field to

```
<%= f.input :time_zone, priority: ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Australia/Perth'], label: 'Your time zone', :label_html => { :class => 'question-project' }, placeholder: 'Select', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 650px', class: 'response-project'} %>
```